# How to make whole bean blonde Starbucks without machine

Tags: coffee

So I just got Starbucks' [Blonde Willow Blend](http://www.starbucksstore.com/starbucks-willow-blend/011017873,default,pd.html) (Whole Bean) and I am very excited to make it, but the problem is I have never done it before and I cannot find any online tutorial for beginners. I also don't have a coffee machine.

I will condense my questions:

1. Do I need to roast the beans? If so, how? Will a pan on the stove do?
2. How can I grind the coffee beans without a coffee grinder? Can a regular grinder work and how fine does it have to be(perhaps how long in seconds)?
3. Is it made into cold or hot coffee? If cold then how much ice? Can I make it in a regular mixer?
4. Does it include milk? If so, how much milk?
5. Can I brew the coffee in a regular pan on fire?

I really want to do it correctly but I can't figure out how. If you can help, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks! And I apologize if my questions don't make sense because I am *completely* new to coffee making.

Comment: Those beans do not need to be roasted.

Comment: @JacobG oh they don't? So i can directly grind them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a grinder and don't have a coffee pot, here's what I would do (I'm assuming you don't also have a coffee filter):

Step 1 - Grind the beans.  If you have a grinder, grind your beans until you have a medium grind:
[image]

Step 2 - Punch a couple of holes into the bottom of a disposable, hot-beverage cup (or a tin can)

Step 3 - Line inside of cup or can from #2 with a handkerchief.  Secure edges of handkerchief around lip of cup with binder clips or a rubberband.

Step 4 - Place grounds into cup.  2-3 tablespoons should be enough.

Step 5 - Place cup over top of empty mug (so coffee can flow into it)

Step 6 - Pour water (very slowly and over all the grounds) that is 5 minutes off the boil over coffee grounds.

You can view a similar tutorial [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/One-Cup-Coffee-Brewing-Cheap-Free-and-Easy/).

Comment: Hmmm I guess I'll rescind my comment. I like my coffee strong lol. I just googled and it sounds right for "regular" coffee.

Comment: For those countries that like salt in their coffee, no need for a clean handkerchief.

Comment: Thanks for a very through and informative answer. This is exactly what i was looking for. This solves my problem! Thanks a ton! D

Comment: @Jacob G Just one more question.. is there any way to make it cold?

Comment: @Achshar - The easiest way to make it cold is to brew it hot and pour it over ice.  There are methods for brewing coffee with cold water, but I can't speak to them as I've never done them.